# Custom User, roles, permissions implementing UserDetail and UserDetailService with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am looking to use Spring Security w/ MySql to store Users, Roles, Permissions (authorities). I have done the following:

ApplicationUser (id, firstName, lastName, username, password, **roles**)
ApplicationRole (id, name, description, **permissions**) implements GrantedAuthority
ApplicationPermission (id, name, description) implements GrantedAuthority

I created a class that implements UserDetailService. In the loadUserByUsername method I doing the following:

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
if(applicationUser == null) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
}

// Extract role/role permission grantedAuthorities from db user
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
for (Role role: applicationUser.getRoles()) {
    grantedAuthorities.add(role);
    grantedAuthorities.addAll(role.getPermissions());
}

return new User(applicationUser.getUsername(), applicationUser.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
```

However, this still leaves me a bit confused and here are a few of my questions...

1. Is it necessary to implement GrantedAuthority on my ApplicationRole
   and ApplicationPermission class. I don't see others doing it in many
   examples that I have seen but it appears to have made my life easier
   so I can just get them and pass them in as is.
2. I have not
   implemented UserDetails with my ApplicationUser class. If I were to
   do this what would be the purpose? Is the only reason so I would be
   able to customize the getAuthorities, isAccountNonExpired,
   isAccountNonLocked, isCredentialsNonExpired, isEnabled methods? Is
   there even a default implementation of these methods or only if I
   create my versions. Why would I need to implement getAuthorities
   here if I am already doing it with loadbyUserName in
   UserDetailsServiceImpl?
3. What is the purpose of SimpleGrantedAuthority? I see it implements GrantedAuthority and only accepts a String name. However, I don't feel like I need to use it since I implemented GrantedAuthority with my ApplicationRole and ApplicationPermission classes.

I think my problem is that I am confused as to when/how to properly implement UserDetail and UserDetailService making sure I am loading the authorities from the database and setting them each time a user logs in. Additionally, is there any point in implementing GrantedAuthority with my ApplicationRole and ApplicationPermission class the way I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not necessary and I wouldn't recommend it either. It's good to keep these different aspects of your application separate. As far as I know it's a common practice to fetch the roles in your custom `UserDetailsService` and wrap their textual representation in a `SimpleGrantedAuthority` (i.e. their name). Note that to differentiate between roles and authorities within Spring Security you have to prefix roles with the `ROLE_` tag by default (see `hasRole` and `hasAuthority` access-control expressions).
2. Having a custom `UserDetails` implementation is not necessary but might have benefits, for example you can store extra fields that are specific to your application. The default implementation is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, most of the time you can just extend this one.
3. See #1

> is there any point in implementing GrantedAuthority with my ApplicationRole and ApplicationPermission class the way I am?

It wouldn't make any sense, no. Many use-cases are covered by the existing implementations, but for the most simple use-cases you can just stick to `SimpleGrantedAuthority`.

Comment: thank you so much. My ultimate goal is to only implement/override or extend when necessary. My main concerns are the following:

1. Have my own Role class that includes custom properties. 2. Have my own Permission class that includes custom properties. 3. Have a User class that includes custom properties and fits in with the rest of Spring security. Be able to persist everything to a MySql database (including the flags that are part of UserDetails entity). Can you let me know if there is anything else I need to know to make this work as clean as possible?

Comment: In addition to what I said above here is my plan: Have ApplicationRole and ApplicationPermission classes that don't implement anything. My ApplicationUser class can extend UserDetails.User rather than implement UserDetails (unless I really need to override the logic in one of the methods). Then finally create a custom implementation of UserDetailsService overriding the loadUserByUsername method, making sure I retrieve the user by username from the db and then send the SimpleGrantedAuthorities to the userdetails. User return value. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: From what you have said I would say you got it pretty much covered. Just try to keep it as simple as possible and only create custom implementations when you see that it is really necessary.